# Does lightning still occur after the blackout?

Tags: tv, revolution

After watching most of the first season I'm wondering if lightning still occurs, or if it is prevented by the "phenomenon" that led to the blackout?

**Followup:**

In the season finale Monroe is standing in a field and suddenly lightning is striking all around him.

Comment: @wbogacz: I'm presuming he's asking about *lightning*, as in the question, and not *lighting*, as in the (former) title, because the latter doesn't make any sense in this context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A reasonable question given the scope and extent of the nanobots. However, I think we can safely say yes lightning does occur for a number of reasons:

1. In the episode The Plague Dogs we saw the storm with the tornado.  We also heard thunder which as far as I am aware would only occur if lightning had.
2. As part of canon, in the Revolution web page companion, in his Journal Aaron mentions lightning.
3. We would have to assume that the overall Earth's magnetic and ionospheric systems have to still be working or we would see mass problems with migratory animals, disruptions in the ozone layer, etc. all of which would cause significant problems for life on the planet including people.
4. We know the nanobots can't be attacking all electricity otherwise the electrical currents within the human body would simply be overwhelmed, killing us.   Hence, there would seem to be some discrimination by the nanobots on what "forms" or "types" of electricity they attack.  Perhaps they can recognize only artificially generated forms of electricity.  If this is the case, then lightning would be excluded.
5. Lightning occurs in a split second.  Per wiki, A bolt of positive lightning may carry an electric current of 300 kA and the potential at the top of the cloud may exceed a billion volts.  For enough nanobots to try and accumulated that quickly to absorb that amount of energy seems unlikely.

[Wiki Lightning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning)

Comment: How do you account for the lightning storm that was occurred near Monroe after the blackout was lifted?

Comment: @JackBNimble Remember the possible outcome of turning the lights back on, why the people in the Tower wanted to prevent it?  I interpreted the lightning as that being on edge, where it could still go either way.